# Kubernetes: How to run a Bash command on Docker container B from Docker container A

Tags: kubernetes

I've set up a simple Kubernetes test environment based on [Docker-Multinode](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-deploy/tree/master/docker-multinode). I've also set up a quite large Docker image based on Ubuntu, which contains several of my tools. Most of them are written in C++ and have quite a lot of dependencies to libraries installed on the system and otherwise.

My goal is to distribute legacy batch tasks between multiple nodes. I liked the easy setup of Docker-Multinode, but now I wonder if this is the right thing for me - since I have my actual legacy applications in the other Docker image.

How can I run a Bash command on Docker container B (the Ubuntu Docker container with my legacy tools) from Docker container A (the multinode worker Docker container)? Or is this not advisable at all?

To clarify, Docker container A (the worker multinode worker Docker container) and Docker container B (the legacy tools Ubuntu Docker container) run on the same host (each machine will have both of them each).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not clear:

Kubernetes runs Docker containers; any Docker container.

Kubernetes itself runs in Docker, and in 'multi-node' the dependencies needed by Kubernetes run in Docker, but in what is called bootstrapped Docker.

Now, it's not clear in your question where Docker A runs, vs. Docker B.
Furthermore, if you want to 'distribute' batch jobs, then each job should be an independent job that runs in its own container and container A should not depend on container A.

If you need the dependencies (libraries) in Docker container B to run your job, then you really only need to use the Docker container B as your base image for your job containers A. A Docker image is layered, so that even if it is big, if another container uses it as a base image, it is only loaded once overall, so it's not a problem to have five containers of type A with B as the base image, because the base image is only loaded once.

If you really need a container to communicate with another, then you should build an API to pass commands from one to the other (a RESTful API of some sort, that can communicate via HTTP calls to pass requests for a process to run on one container and return a result).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question to clarify that docker A and B run both on each server both. So one thing I was considering was using docker socket to have the worker docker start a sibling (not child) docker B. But in fact I have no idea which image is used by docker-multinode. And likely it's not a Ubuntu image either. Which image and how would I change it within the docker-multinode example?

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to run one container from another. What is the goal? In Kubernetes your run Pods (whether they are Pods controlled by Deployment, PetSets or Jobs). I am not sure what your Docker container A has to do with this here; it's just running the Kubernetes services, then just use the Kubernetes command line to run your B container.

Comment: I mean that I'd then like to use container A with the services in it and install all legacy stuff into it. Then I don't need container B. But I don't know which image A has, it's buried in the bash dcripts and there seem several different.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of Docker. Docker is meant to containerize services, that is, 1 function = 1 container. So buils you image for your own service and run that, and don't try to put stuff in other services's containers.

Comment: But how do I add a service to the docker-multinode example? E.g. I want to consume a task from a queue in "docker B"? It's all set up and controlled by the example scripts, and I don't see how to integrate my own service. I have an idea how that would work using other examples, but not in docker-multinode...

Comment: i don't know what example script you are talking about: the guthub project lets you deploy a multi node Kubernetes cluster. Kubernetes lets you orchestrate docker containers, so now you have your cluster set up, read up on Kunernetes and define a Pod to run your own application. You might need a Kubernetes Service as well to access your Pod easily and send it whatever request to run. http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/quick-start/

Comment: ps: if you are new to Docker, maybe a good thing would be to learn Docker before you move to Kubernetes. Kubernetes is another level of abstraction to manage Docker containers in distributed fashion, and there are lots of concepts that can be confusing if you're not familiar with containers.